# My session variables won't update (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, model-view-controller, session-variables

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm trying to understand the basics.
My application follows the MVC framework and i'm trying to update a session variable from my controller, then access it from my views.

Here's my code in my controller (this is the only place I update the variable):

```
def testLogin_method
  if(!session[:loggedIn])
    session[:loggedIn] = true;
  else
    session[:loggedIn] = false;
    redirect_to(static_pages_login_url);
  end
end

helper_method :testLogin_method
```

I call this method when I click the login button in my view using javascript :

```
function login(){
  <% testLogin_method %>
}
```

And I call it when I logout :

```
<li><%= link_to raw('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out'), :controller => "static_pages", :action => "testLogin_method" %></li>
```

My problem is, when I logout, the application does redirect to the login page, but the session[:loggedIn] stays at true. How do I keep it to false?

Edit: How could I toggle a variable session from true to false? The login/logout is just for context, I don't want to actually make an authentification.

P.S. I'm not using Gem Devise, because I just want to understand how the session variables works, this is just an example.

Comment: Skip the javascript for now. You seem confused enough anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Does your javascript method work?

Because it that's not how helpers work. It will call the `testLogin_method` when it renders the page, NOT when javascript executes. Check the source of rendered JS

Helpers are used on the server side to help render the page. On the client side you'll have to make an ajax call from javascript to the `testLogin_method`

Comment: Yeah it works, but before I call <% testLogin_method %> it says my session variable is undefined, then after it says true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a decent example of how to use sessions consider this example:

```
# config/routes.rb
resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
end

 # app/helpers/session_helper.rb
module SessionHelper
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    current_user.is_a?(User)
  end
end

# app/controllers/session_controller.rb
class SessionController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    reset_session
    @user = User.find_by(params[:email])
    if @user.try(:authenticate, params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to :root, success: 'You have been signed in.'
    else
      render :new, error: 'Wrong email or password.'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    flash[:success] = 'You have been signed out.' 
    respond_to do |f|
      f.html { redirect_to :root }
      f.json { head :ok } 
    end
  end
end
```

This is the simplest possible session based authentication system. Users can log in via `POST /session` and out through `DELETE /session`.

When we log users out we call `reset_session` which nulls the entire session - preventing session fixation attacks.

If we wanted to sign a user out via javascript we would send an ajax request to `DELETE /session`.

```
<%= button_to session_path, id: 'logout', method: :delete, remote: { true , type: 'json' } do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out
<% end %>
```

We then setup an ajax listener to reload the page:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#logout', function(){
  Turbolinks.clearCache();
  Turbolinks.visit(location.toString());
});
```

You could update the page in place to change the state between signed in and out - but a better solution is to flush the cache and reload the page. Since otherwise your login/out handler has to keep track of any `if user_signed_in?` type conditionals on the page.

Comment: The keen will notice that you accomplish nothing really by using ajax. A plain old `button_to` would do the job just as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great example for authentification, but it doesn't answer my question, I just want to know why is it not updating? I used the terms login and logout for context. How do I toggle a session variable on/off?

Comment: Your whole example is completely broken since you don't seem to understand what happens on the server side vs client side. The reason your example does not work is that  `<% testLogin_method %>` is evaluted when the view is rendered. Not when the javascript is executed.

Comment: Then how would I call my controller's method from my view?

Comment: You don't call a controllers methods from the view. The user clicks links and forms which creates HTTP requests that your controller responds to. If you want to do this via javascript you need to send an ajax request. But again. Learn ruby & then rails the old fashioned syncronous way. Once you understand MVC and the client/server model you can start doing ajax.

Comment: @baash05 you do realize that ajax is a term for sending asyncronous HTTP requests with JS?